# in ERD do I need to make 2 tables of booking request and proposal or should I need to make one table for this

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, erd

If I am developing a Fiverr like platform where a freelancer can send proposals on the job to client and client can send a booking request to freelancers as well, so in ERD do I need to make 2 tables of booking request and proposal or should I need to make one table for this?

Comment: What have you done so far?  There's really not enough information in your question to indicate a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do both.

## One table

When you make one table (e.g. `booking_requests`) you will propably need an additional attributed in the relation itself, which indicates if it is a client requesting or a freelancer proposing. The table will be a 1:1 relationship. For example (for the relationship table):

```
freelancer_id
client_id
requested
```

Where you can define the attribute `requested` to hold for example `1` for request and `0` for proposal.

## Two tables

You can add two relationships between the freelancer and the client, one `proposals` and one `requests`. Both will be 1:1 and hold the same attributes `freelancer_id` and `client_id`.

These are two possible ways to implement this problem, there are probably a lot more. It all depends on the rest of you database schema and the implementation of your application.